# Android Service in background thread

Tags: android, android-service

I'm trying to create a service that runs in a given interval. The service's purpose is to update a database and when done notify an `Activity` with an `Intent`.

The service should also be callable from the activity when the user chooses to 'refresh'.

I have accomplished this, but I can't get it to run in a detached thread.

The service executes an update method in a Runnable:

```
private Runnable refresh = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            update();   //Runs updates
            didUpdate(); //Sends broadcast
            handler.postDelayed(this, 50000); // 50 seconds, calls itself in 50 secs
        }
    };
```

I have another runnable called ManualRefresh that is called via a broadcast from the activity.

However these runnables seem to be blocking the UI.

Need advice! :)

Comment: How are you running the Runnables?

Comment: I do it by calling refresh.run()

Comment: may be try to run it by , handler.post(refresh);

Comment: @Yashwanth - using a Handler would run it on the UI thread; exactly what OP doesn't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run a Runnable by calling it's `run` method, it runs on the current thread. To run on a background thread, you need to use `new Thread(refresh).start();` (if the Runnable you want run is `refresh`).

You can also make use of AsyncTask for this, but that's more appropriate for an activity than for a Service. Information about using AsyncTask can be found in the [API docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and in the article [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to write the service using the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).  The service will receive an Intent to tell it to periodically to update the database.

Once updated, you can notify the Activity with an Intent (as you mentioned).

When the user wants to manually refresh, have the Application sent an Intent to you service.  Receiving the Intent from the AlarmManager or from the Activity would perform the same code.

You may also want to reschedule the alarm after a request to manually refresh.